# Extension warning in VS code

Tags: visual-studio-code, nativescript

I get this warning when opening a fresh-new NativeScript (Angular) in VS code.

**The below 1 extension(s) in workspace recommendations have issues: telerik.nativescript (not found in marketplace)**

Should I ignore the warning or delete **telerik.nativescript** in the **extension.json** while I develop the app?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have also been getting this notification wondering what it was after creating a new NativeScript Angular project. It seems like NativeScript is trying to recommend their NativeScript extension in VSCode https://nativescript.org/nativescript-for-visual-studio-code/.

I don't have this recommendation or `extensions.json` file on my older projects so I'm sure you can **delete** the file/recommendations and decide for yourself if you want to install their extension without affecting your project.

```
{
    "recommendations": []
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. I will check to see if I need the extension.

Answer (score 1):

I think that this extension was probably renamed from "telerik.nativescript" to "NativeScript.nativescript" because in my case:

- I was having the same problem described above "not found in marketplace"
- I had an (old) nativescript extension already installed on my system (probably installed a year ago)
- The VSCODE was kind of confused... checking the installed extensions was pointing me to the new one, but at the same time was telling me that it was not installed!?

Solution:

- VSCODE: Extensions: NativeScript => [Unistall] followed by a [Install]
- Source Code: "recommendations" changed "telerik.nativescript" to "NativeScript.nativescript"

Now everything seems to be in order.

Comment: Thank you for the solution. In my case, I realize that after a short time, the error disappear so maybe there's something wrong with VScode or NativeScript I installed. So in the end, I just ignored it.

Answer (score 0):

Just to add some more detail, the file that needs to be changed in your NativeScript projects is **".vscode\extensions.json"**

The code needs to be changed from:

```
{
    "recommendations": [
        "telerik.nativescript"
    ]
}
```

To:

```
{
    "recommendations": [
        "NativeScript.nativescript"
    ]
}
```

@antseq is correct that the extension was renamed from `"telerik.nativescript"` to `"NativeScript.nativescript"`.